# Navigation bar not displaying correctly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

My bootstrap navbar was working just fine when suddenly it decided to stop displaying correctly. I have no idea why this happened. Until a day back it was working fine. Then I updated my app engine and suddenly everything went haywire. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n35oY.png).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Class A Part - Admin Login</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />

<!-- StyleSheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/custom.css" />
</head>

<body>
<!-- Navigation Bar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

         </a>
        <a href="studentLogin.jsp" class="brand" style="text-align:center" >Class A Part</a>

    <div class="nav-collapse collapse pull-right">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#forgot" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Forgot Password</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="modal"><i class="icon-envelope icon-white"></i> Contact Us</a></li>
            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>

        </ul>
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Navigation Ends -->

<!-- Main Container -->
<section>
<div class="container login">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="center span4 well">
            <legend>Please Sign In</legend>
            <div class="alert alert-error">
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>Incorrect UserName or Password!
            </div>
            <form method="POST" action="/LoginProcess" accept-charset="UTF-8">
            <input type="text" id="username" class="span4" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
            <input type="password" id="password" class="span4" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
            <label class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1" /> Remember Me
            </label>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<p class="text-center muted ">&copy; Copyright 2014 - G1T1</p>
</section>
<!-- Main Container Ends -->

<!-- Forgot Password Model Box -->
<div id="forgot" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">
<div class="modal-header">
<a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
<h3>Forgot Password</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Enter your username to reset the password</p>
<form>
      <div class="controls controls-row">
          <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Name" />
      </div>

</form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Contact Us Model Box -->
<div id="contact" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">
<div class="modal-header">
<a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
<h3>Contact Us</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form>
      <div class="controls controls-row">
          <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="span3" placeholder="Name" />
      </div>

       <div class="controls controls-row">
       <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="span3" placeholder="Email address" />
       </div>

      <div class="controls">
          <textarea id="message" name="message" class="span5" placeholder="Your Message" rows="5"></textarea>
      </div>

  </form>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
</div>
</div>

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does updating your app engine mean? If you use SVN or Git you could look at the latest history and see every change that was made yesterday.

Comment: What's not "correct" about it?

Comment: I'm out of time, but here's a starting-point fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/hgh3h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are updated to Bootstarp 3, while the HTML structure and CSS classes remains same as Bootstrap 2.